# pusher presence can't get members using angularjs and golang

Tags: javascript, angularjs, go, pusher

I am trying to use the examples from [here](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels) so far this is what I have setup

// angularjs

```
    // JS
    var presenceClient = new Pusher('API_KEY', {
        authEndpoint: apiServer + "/presence_auth",
        authTransport: 'jsonp',
        encrypted: true            
    })


    var c = pusher.subscribe("presence-testchan")
    Utils.log(c.members.count) // 0
    Utils.log("000============")    
    c.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
        Utils.log("succeeded?")
        Utils.log(members)
    })
```

// golang and the presence endpoint

```
func Presence(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc) {
    params, _ := GetBytes(r.URL.String())

    presenceData := pusher.MemberData{
        UserId: database.GenerateStrObjID(),
        UserInfo: map[string]string{
            "twitter": "pusher",
        },
    }
    response, err := PusherClient.AuthenticatePresenceChannel(params, presenceData)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    respondToJSON(w, string(response))
}


func respondToJSON(w http.ResponseWriter, data interface{}) {

    r := render.New()
    r.JSON(w, http.StatusOK, data)
}
```

I guess that is the basic form. but I don't get any members count?. I can get a response from the API with

```
"{\"auth\":\"7d6e393c49c579c43a0c:6cd45662ef57fbc3ab16d8052c43bf95e7415846f736c2499bac7628ca3b75bc\",\"channel_data\":\"{\\\"user_id\\\":\\\"56f9e5ffcc1cb466a624a3cf\\\",\\\"user_info\\\":{\\\"twitter\\\":\\\"pusher\\\"}}\"}"
```

but has error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Am I missing something or my setup is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, solved the problem.. it's missing in the docs for Go examples to return it in `jsonp` with callback func. response should have something like this...

```
Pusher.auth_callbacks['1']({auth: "7d6e393c49c579c43a0c:33a442fcc9d3bf67febfeeb59e5a8e4f0364901069534cdef006b0b047df9f75",…});
auth:"7d6e393c49c579c43a0c:33a442fcc9d3bf67febfeeb59e5a8e4f0364901069534cdef006b0b047df9f75"
channel_data :"{"user_id":"56fa1231cc1cb48a1cdb243c","user_info":{"twitter":"pusher"}}"
```